# Why is it that my Prometheus Operator ServiceMonitor needs a `release` label to run properly?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator

When I deploy this:

```
kind: ServiceMonitor
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: complaints-monitor
    release: prometheus # <---------
  name: complaints-monitor-svc-monitor
  namespace: default
spec:
  endpoints:
    - path: /metrics
      port: web
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - default
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: complaints-monitor
```

My service shows up under prometheus targets and runs correctly.

If I apply the following instead, the target disappears:

```
kind: ServiceMonitor
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: complaints-monitor
  name: complaints-monitor-svc-monitor
  namespace: default
spec:
  endpoints:
    - path: /metrics
      port: web
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - default
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: complaints-monitor
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just figured out this problem after checking the `values.yaml` of `kube-prometheus-stack`

- [vaules.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/f9231870934581b09c40371b2d80d049d866a4ab/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2178-L2191)

```yaml
    ## If true, a nil or {} value for prometheus.prometheusSpec.serviceMonitorSelector will cause the
    ## prometheus resource to be created with selectors based on values in the helm deployment,
    ## which will also match the servicemonitors created
    ##
    serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: true


    ## ServiceMonitors to be selected for target discovery.
    ## If {}, select all ServiceMonitors
    ##
    serviceMonitorSelector: {}
    ## Example which selects ServiceMonitors with label "prometheus" set to "somelabel"
    # serviceMonitorSelector:
    #   matchLabels:
    #     prometheus: somelabel
```

When you use helm to install `kube-prometheus-stack`, it adds label `release: <prometheus-installed-namespace>` to Kubernetes resource.

If setting `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` is `true` a selector will be add to `prometheus.prometheusSpec.serviceMonitorSelector`, in your case is `release: prometheus`.

You shall be able to see the selector for prometheus to select serviceMonitor with command

```
kubectl -n <prometheus-installed-namespace> get prometheus -o yaml
```

and search for `serviceMonitorSelector`.

You have two options to get it work without adding `release` label

1. Set `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` to `false`, then prometheus will select all serviceMonitor
2. Or, set `serviceMonitorSelector` to any label you like.